# How to bake textures with compositing applied?

Tags: texture-baking, baking, effects

How to bake textures with compositing applied? I do some compositing with Compositing Nodes and I want to apply it to all of my baked textures. In other words I wanna bake with post-processing to bake all that beautiful stuff that I've made with my Compositing Nodes :)

Comment: Good question. It might not be possible at this time. Maybe somebody knows any workarounds.

Comment: Whoa yeah I love the idea. Don't think it's currently possible, tho

Comment: Depending on what you are doing in the compositor, you could bake the texture and then input the baked image into the compositor and save the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could try saving the image as close to the size of your texture as you can get and projection-mapping it (this does mean you'll need to render a few times, though). EDIT: You'd need to render at least one more time to get the back, and possibly a few more for more obscure angles and stitch the images together either via UV layers or externally, or, my favorite, with masking maps.